# what's the line meaning in jquery?

Tags: jquery

```
 var selector = $('#foo');
 var html = selector.wrap('<div/>').parent().html();
  selector.unwrap();
```

i am new to jquery, i don't understand the second line well, expect some can explain to me. thank you,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if there is en element with id = Foo, say a span

```
<span id="Foo"></span>
```

the second line will [wrap](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) it in a `div` element, like:

```
<div>
     <span id="Foo"></span>
</div>
```

and return the innerHtml property of the parent of the element with id = Foo, i.e., it will return `<span id="Foo"></span>`.

Comment: why it can't use var html = $("#Foo").html();

Comment: @zhuanzhou - As @SLaks says in his answer, "*It's a hack to get the original element's outer HTML, including its start and end tag.*", otherwise you'd just get the contents of the `Foo` element, without opening and closing tags.

Answer (score 5):

The [`.wrap()` method](http://api.jquery.com/wrap) wraps a new element around the element in a jQuery object.
The `.parent()` method selects this new element.
The `.html` method returns the HTML inside the wrapping element.

It's a hack to get the original element's **outer** HTML, including its start and end tag.

Comment: +1 it's a shame `outerHTML` isn't used where available; both Chrome and IE support it and it would be faster.

Answer (score 1):

The second line is taking the DOM element stored in `selector`, wrapping it in a `<div/>` element with `.wrap('<div/>')`, getting the parent of the original `selector` element (which is now that new ) with `.parent()`, and returning the html of it with `.html()`, which is stored in the variable `html`